# Converting a Popup to Relative Isn't Working

Tags: css, popup, css-position

I have an old piece of code that pops up a message on moseover. It is coded with absolute positioning and works fine. But I need to change it to relative positioning so the code works better with mobile devices. In this [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/user3052443/oL9gz8zs/) the top line is using relative and doesn't work. The bottom line is using absolute and is working. Would someone please point out where I am going wrong? Here's my code:

```
    <style>
    .tooltips {
      position: relative;
      display: inline;
    }
    .spank{
      position: absolute;
      width:250px;
      color: #000;
      background: #FFFFFF;
      border: 1px solid #ccc;
      padding:10px;
      text-align: center;
      display:none;
      border-radius: 7px;
      box-shadow: -1px 0px 7px #ccc;
    }
    .spank:before {
      content: '';
      position: absolute;
      top: 100%;
      left: 50%;
      margin-left: -12px;
      width: 0; height: 0;
      border-top: 10px solid #ccc;
      border-right: 10px solid transparent;
      border-left: 12px solid transparent;
    }
    .spank:after {
      content: '';
      position: absolute;
      top: 100%;
      left: 50%;
      margin-left: -8px;
      width: 0; height: 0;
      border-top: 8px solid #FFFFFF;
      border-right: 8px solid transparent;
      border-left: 8px solid transparent;
    }
    .showhim:hover .spank{
      display : block;
      left:5px;
      top:1px;
      margin-left: 50px;
      z-index: 999
    }
    .showhim {
      left: 50px;
      position: relative;
      top: 80px;
      width: 100px;
    }

    .spankme{
      position: absolute;
      width:250px;
      color: #000;
      background: #FFFFFF;
      border: 1px solid #ccc;
      padding:10px;
      text-align: center;
      display:none;
      border-radius: 7px;
      box-shadow: -1px 0px 7px #ccc;
    }
    .spankme:before {
      content: '';
      position: absolute;
      top: 100%;
      left: 50%;
      margin-left: -12px;
      width: 0; height: 0;
      border-top: 10px solid #ccc;
      border-right: 10px solid transparent;
      border-left: 12px solid transparent;
    }
    .spankme:after {
      content: '';
      position: absolute;
      top: 100%;
      left: 50%;
      margin-left: -8px;
      width: 0; height: 0;
      border-top: 8px solid #FFFFFF;
      border-right: 8px solid transparent;
      border-left: 8px solid transparent;
    }
    .showme:hover .spankme{
      display : block;
      left: 10px;
      top:10px;
      margin-left:50px;
      z-index: 999
    }
    .showme { 
      position: relative;
      width: 100px;
    } 
    </style>

    <div class="showme">
     <div class="showme tooltips">Mouse me</div>
     <span class="spankme">Text on popupPlace</span>
    </div>   

    <div class="showhim">
     <div class="showit tooltips">Mouse me</div>
     <span class="spank">Text on popupPlace</span>
    </div>
```

Comment: What exactly are you trying to change to be relative? The actual pop ups?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the hover that applies to .spankme, you aren't targeting the parent like you did with .spank.  The following will allow the parent to reference the child on hover.

Change

```
.showme:hover .spankme
```

to

```
.showhim:hover .spankme
```

Also, you have three z-index: 999 properties that are missing a closing semi-colon.